# Why is dask.bag.Bag.take(3) only returning one value?

Tags: dask

This example is taken straight from the docs here:  https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/bag-api.html#dask.bag.Bag.take

```
from dask.bag import from_sequence
b = from_sequence(range(10))
b.take(3)
```

It is supposed to print

```
(0,1,2)
```

But for me it prints

```
(0,)
```

This is with dask 2.20.0 and python 3.8.

`b.compute()` prints `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` as you would expect.  I am just learning dask and this behavior of `take(3)` seems very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that there is some problem with the documentation. According to the docs "*if there are fewer than `k` rows in the first `npartitions` a warning will be raised and any found rows returned*" but in this case no warning is returned.

```py
from dask.bag import from_sequence
b = from_sequence(range(10))
```

If you `print(b)` it returns

```sh
dask.bag<from_se..., npartitions=10>
```

So here you have 10 partitions and, according to docs, `b.take(3)` should return `(0,)` and a warning. If you repartition your bag as `b = b.repartition(2)` then `b.take(3)` returns `(0, 1, 2)`.

**Update**
As I said it was a problem within the documentations. This has been fixed [here](https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/6418#event-3555281357).